# Quiche does not set up - too much, or too little, cream?

Tags: custard, ratio, quiche

My quiche did not set up well; the final custard remained a touch watery/soft.

Would that mean my ratio of cream : egg was too **much** or too **little** cream?

What's the logic of quiche custard?

Should I now try a bit **more** or a bit **less** cream?

You can often find mentioned the finding from French cuisine that "3:2" is thought to be the best ratio ... but no-one really mentions which "way" that goes!

---

FTR thanks to the below,

3 eggs to exactly 1 cup *full* cream works perfectly for quiche. (A 9" pie.)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You need less cream for a firmer consistency. The eggs are the part that set during the cooking process. The cream adds moisture and fat, both of which make it softer and runnier.

Comment: Thanks!  So indeed then.  I guess using all-cream (rather than cream/milk) indeed also makes it softer/runnier.

Comment: @Fattie milk is waterier and will make it runnier. Cream is fattier and will make it softer.

Comment: !!!  OK, got it.

Comment: I tried 3 eggs and exactly 1 cup full cream - works great  :)

Comment: Hey Thx @Fattie

Answer (score 1):

Add 1 Tab of flour in egg mix. That works for me. Check Moosewood cool books Quiches. Easy and my go-to for 38 years.

Comment: Adding a little bit of starch also helps to stop the eggs from separating if they coagulate 'too hard'. (Also useful when making other custards, although I generally use cornstarch instead of flour, as it has a more neutral flavour.)